# Dataframe Row to JSON giving incorrect result

Tags: json, python-3.x

I need to convert each row of DataFrame to JSON.

Each row is converted to JSON by the following line of script:

```
data = df.loc[0].to_json()
```

Output:

```
{
    "uid": "1234",
    "url": "https:\\/\\/google.com",
    "name": "google.com",
    "queries": [
        "Query1",
        "Query2",
        "Query3"
    ]
}
```

Why is it not parsing the URLs properly?

Ideally, the JSON format of the records should be like below, isn't it?

```
{
    "uid": "1234",
    "url": "https:\/\/google.com",
    "name": "google.com",
    "queries": [
        "Query1",
        "Query2",
        "Query3"
    ]
}
```

This is how the df looks:

[image]

Comment: What's df look like?

Comment: @hd1 modified the question, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

json.dumps(df.loc[0].to_dict()) returns the data as json, without escaping the URLs. See below:

```
In[19]: df
Out[19]: 
    uid                 url        name                   queries
0  1234  https://google.com  google.com  [Query1, Query2, Query3]

In [20]: json.dumps(df.loc[0].to_dict())
Out[20]: '{"uid": "1234", "url": "https://google.com", "name": "google.com", "queries": ["Query1", "Query2", "Query3"]}'
```